# Retrieve text alignment from TextRenderInfo in LocationTextExtractionStrategy

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I've written a LocationTextExtractionStrategy handler to extract the text and graphics in C# from a PDF using iText7. All of the items are being extracted correctly but it appears that some of the text is right-aligned. The bounds of the text are correct but the text should be right-aligned in the bounds which means it appears incorrectly when rendered.

You can see the bounds and text here; the enumerators are supposed to be right-aligned:

[image]

I've compared all of the properties of the TextRenderInfo class but can't see how I can determine that the text is right aligned. The properties seem to have the same values for left and right aligned text.

```
// Automatically called for each chunk of text in the PDF
public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    // Grab the individual characters
    var chars = renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos().ToList();

    // Grab the first and last character
    var firstChar = chars.First();
    var lastChar = chars.Last();

    // Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
    var bottomLeft = firstChar.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
    var topRight = lastChar.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

    var font = renderInfo.GetFont();
    var fontName = font.GetFontProgram().GetFontNames().GetFontName();

    // How do I know the text alignment?

    var shape = new Shapes.Text(
        $"t{_textId++}",
        new PointF(bottomLeft.Get(Vector.I1), bottomLeft.Get(Vector.I2)),
        new PointF(topRight.Get(Vector.I1), topRight.Get(Vector.I2)))
    {
        Runs = new List<Run>
        {
            new Run(renderInfo.GetText())
            {
                Bold = fontName.Contains("Bold"),
                Italic = fontName.Contains("Italic"),
                Size = renderInfo.GetFontSize()
            }
        }
    };

    _shapes.Add(shape);
}
```

Comment: PDFs don't have different alignments. You always start drawing a string from the origin of its leftmost character, i.e. left-aligned. Any text *appearing* right-/center-/block-aligned actually is drawn left-aligned with explicitly calculated start coordinates (and spacings) to generate that appearance. (Actually PDF also supports top-aligned vertical writing but that apparently is not what you're after.)